# Ouput impedance of a balun

Tags: impedance, differential, network, matching, balun

I am using the CC1110 RF IC and I am having trouble when matching the differential RF output impedance with the antenna. The datasheet states that the differential impedance seen from the RF output towards the antenna must be: $$(86.5+\mathrm j43)\Omega$$ when operating at 868 MHz.

The application circuit proposes a balun and matching network for a 50 Ω load but mine isn't. I want to know if I'm doing my calculations correctly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7UJvo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am simulating the above schematic (don't take into account component values shown as they are not the used ones) with a AC current source (I1) with 1 amp AC magnitude and measuring voltage across its terminals and calculating the impedance as
$$|Z|=\frac{V_{RF_P}-V_{RF_N}}{I_1}$$
$$\angle Z=\angle(V_{RF_P}-V_{RF_N})-\angle I_1$$
$$Z=|Z|\exp(\mathrm j \angle Z)$$

Are my calculations correct? Is this impedance found (Z) the one that has to be matched to the value specified above?

---

### Edit

After @Bimpelrekkie I performed the simulation using the values stated in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1110-cc1111.pdf) (page 38-40) and obtained this output:

[image]

The amplitude and phase difference are:
$$\frac{V_{RF_P}-V_{RF_N}}{I_1}=126.52\ \Omega$$
$$\angle(V_{RF_P}-V_{RF_N})-\angle I_1=1.21\ \mathrm{rad}$$
Which gives an impedance of:
$$Z=(46.6+\mathrm j118.7)\Omega$$
Which is far from the (86.5+j43)Ω stated in the datasheet?

Are my simulations wrong? Is the application circuit wrong?

Comment: I agree with the first formula for \$|Z|\$, not sure about the other two, is that the real and imaginary part of Z? Indeed you will have to make Z(s) = 86.5 + 43j and should then match the IC's outputs.

Comment: In the second formula what I'm saying is that the phase of the impedance is the phase difernce between voltage acros the source, and current. Is this correct?
Then I just calculate the complex impedance based on modulus and phase.

Comment: Oh, OK if you prefer it that way then go ahead. For me dealing with the phase seems overly complex, I prefer to deal with real and imaginary parts. But that's personal preference. Some people prefer to use a Smith Chart.

Comment: The problem is that I'm jot familiar with this kind of concepts. I've never used a Smith Chart nor know how to use it. I just want to know if my understanding of the "differential impedance" is correct: the impedance between + ans - ports.

Comment: Join the company, even though I'm an experienced RF designer I do not use the Smith Chart, I just use a plot or Re(Z) and I(Z) instead (which shows essentially the same information) and I manage with that fine. Yes your differential impedance is indeed as you define it, between + and - inputs. It is also correct to simulate that with a 1 A AC current source so you can just plot the voltage as that will be identical to Z (because I = 1).

Comment: please, see my edit

Comment: You really should consider using an AC analysis and then plotting Re(Z) and Im(Z) over frequency, then you can more easily see where (at what frequency) your circuit is properly matched. Also you might have to change the component values a bit to get the proper match. At 868 MHz, component parasitics (like pcb capacitance, capacitor inductance, trace inductance) play a **very** important role. So even if you find the ideal solution in a simulator, you still need to measure and tweak that on the PCB. That's the "black magic" part of RF design ;-)

Comment: Do you think the difference in impedance may be due to the parasitic capacitances?

Comment: **No/Yes** ;-) **No**, not now because you're only simulating so everything is **ideal** no parasitics etc. You would have to **model** those parasitics yourself. That's not easy because you do not know yet what they will be. **Yes**, because later when you're actually building this with **real components** on a PCB the parasitic components **will** be there and then **will** bug you. No one ever said RF was easy (especially for beginners).